# Normal range for d3.js diagram usind domain method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, sparklines

Here [a link](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2013-12-19) with fantastic description of sparklines implementation using d3.js

I'm doing something similar but I need to define a normal range for each sparkline, like here on mockup :

[image]

This grey bar is hard coded now. The meaning of this bar is to represent "green" range of data. For example from 0 to 1. Everything that is less or more then this range should be not in that bar.

I have such domain in my js file:

```
    y.domain(
    d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.y;
})
```

and this is how i`m drawing my greybar:

```
    var baseline = graph.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", y(2))
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", y(3))
    .attr("class", "rect_");
```

But when I'll give for this block of code my normal range [0,1]

```
     var baseline = graph.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", y(1))
    .attr("class", "rect_");
```

I'm getting this :

[image]

I'm afraid it`s complete incorrect way , need someone help, thanx!

Comment: How is it not working? Is the rect not appearing at the position where y is 0?

Comment: you can see if the input data is [2,3] - the result is much better :) but real [0.1] data is awful

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. It looks to me like it's putting the `rect` exactly where you're asking it to put it.

Comment: yep , but there is need to put this rect like on first mockup , but using real normal range

Comment: So is your question about how to determine the "normal range"?

Comment: basically yes, if I have two diagrams , one have NR [0,3] , other [0,1]

Comment: Well if you know the normal range then the `y` position would be the midpoint between the extremes and the `height` half the range.

Comment: yes, but i should not be coupled with midpoint, normal range can be changed later, so i just need to convert my normal range to coordinates. If i have values for line like : 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 , 1 , -2 - only 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 should be in normal range bar , and others - outer

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Would the normal range in your example not be [0.1, 0.5]?

Comment: 0.1 0.5 0.3 - data that is in normal range
normal range is all numbers from 0 to 0.99

Comment: I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: You have sparkline of human temperature, and you have measurements of your temperature for a month. Normal range for human temperature is from 35.8(c) to 36.8(c). Suppose for a week you have temperature  from 37 to 38 , this is not normal, so it must be shown out of normal range, like in first picture i've attached. maybe now its clearer :)

Comment: I don't see the problem with determining the position and dimensions of the rectangle. In this case, y = 36.3 and height = 1.

Comment: how it will be in java script code? thanx

Comment: `var y = (max - min)/2, height = max - min;`

Comment: for range [0, 1] bar is drawing well, but [0,3] - bar doesnt draw

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete working example that demonstrates the problem.